# IIF statement not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdlc

`=IIF(Fields!Date.Value = "", "Some Text", Fields!Date.Value)`

I have the above statement in a report, and if the `date value is NULL`, then this will return "Some Text", however instead of returning the `date` when the `date field has a value` i get `#error`

My understanding of the expression is that if the condition is met return "Some Text" otherwise return `Fields!Date.Value`

Why do I get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do that like this

```
=IIF(Fields!Date.Value Is Nothing, "No Value", Fields!Date.Value)
```

The `IIF()` statement has the following `format`:

```
=IIF( Expression to evaluate,
         what-to-do when the expression is true,
         what-to-do when the expression is false )
```

- **`Parameter1`**: It should be a `Boolean` `Expression`.
- **`Paremeter2`**: This    value will return when `Expression` is `true`.
- **`Paremeter3`**: This value    will return when `Expression` is `false`.